# How do you switch ngrok accounts from cli?

Tags: ngrok

I am trying to access a subdomain belonging to a separate ngrok account.

How do I logout and login to a different ngrok account from the command line on a macbook?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. You need to access your ngrok authToken and paste the following in the terminal:

```
ngrok authtoken AUTH_TOKEN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to stop using the account entirely and move to the trial provision.

I did this by locating the `.ngrok.yml` file where the authtoken is being stored and commented this line out.

The file was located in the default location for this is: `~/.ngrok2/ngrok.yml` unless you specified a different location when registering the account on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

For logout locate ngrok.yml file , edit it and remove authotoken line and save it.